# Why doesn't this button work in Firefox on Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm hoping someone out there can tell me what's causing the "Continue" button to fail on Firefox with Mac.  It's a simple form with a button to select one's country.  I'm with a non-profit trying to raise funds for end-of-year giving to help save animals and this page works on "most" browsers:  Windows FF, IE, older IE, Chrome, and Mac Safari and Chrome.  However, it seems to fail completely on FF on Mac and I don't know why.

The code is all there in the page:  www.ifaw.org/united-states/holiday-gift

I'm guessing that the problem is that FF in Mac isn't running the onclick="selectTheRightCountry();" routine.  But Javascript is on, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

I'm afraid most of my web designing is based on Windows and I'm not a guru in cross-browser Javascript, so I'm not sure what the best way to fix this would be.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be limited to older versions of Firefox on Mac.  Would still be interested to know what caused it if anyone knows, but it's not a huge deal anymore.  Thank you!